# GCP App Engine won't upload files to Cloud Storage (Node/Express)

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, storage

I'm creating a small upload site for a group of colleagues using App Engine - the site simply provides an interface for a user to upload a CSV file to a cloud storage bucket.

The app uses a React front end service, and a Node Express backend service.

I've got everything running perfectly fine locally (using the keyfile of a service account, can confirm not using default/local credentials), selecting a file, processing it and uploading it to the storage bucket from localhost works as expected (200 response)

The interesting part is when I deploy this to App Engine, the site appears to work as expected, when selecting and uploading a file the console shows a 200 OK response (very quickly might I add, compared to the local version) yet it doesn't upload anything.

I'm struggling to find backend logs to suggest why this isn't working, can't seem to get my node logs from express to appear anywhere in stack driver.

Is there something I'm overlooking here?

Comment: It will be hard for us to provide any help without a look at your code, share at least the relevant parts interacting with cloud storage please